# Any advanced email searching/sorting plugin for Thunderbird 3.1.*?

Tags: email, thunderbird

I got close to a thousand email daily. Is there any nice email searching (supporting regex, checking multiple fields, etc.) and sorting plugin I can use with Thunderbird?

I sometimes use Mutt but it's not available on a few computers I use.

Comment: You don't specify an operating system - what operating system(s) do you want the solution to work for? Also, are you willing to pay for a solution or want free or only OSS?

Comment: OS: mostly Linux and Mac OS X, rarely Windows.
Both OSS and non-free software are OK.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it is the wrong approach to do have the sorting done by the client. Ideally, mail should be sorted by the server when it arrives (i.e. not be placed in your inbox but elsewhere).

A setup that does very well performing that task is the dovecot MDA with sieve support - sieve is a protocol that allows every user to write a rules file that is then used by the server to sort the mail on arrival. Clients can contact the sieve service to edit the rules. There exists a Thunderbird Plugin [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/thunderbird/addon/sieve/), RoundCube webmail also has support for it:

[image]

Comment: The problem is I don't have control of the email server and can't install anything like `sieve`.